# Details About: ReadonlySet?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, readonly

Is `ReadonlySet` means set of `ReadOnly` properties as same as [ReadOnlyCollection in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx)? 
I am not able to find out any document for it from anywhere. Could you please let me know what is the use of `ReadonlySet` and How can we do implementation of it?

```
let readonly: Readonly<number> = 1;
let readonlySet: ReadonlySet<number> = ???//
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I thought the function of `ReadOnlySet` is same as `ReadOnlyCollection` which is I have using in C#(backend). I don't get any document for this.

Comment: (Yes, I saw the edit.) If it's in code you're using, you must be able to figure out what's providing it and, from there, find the documentation or source code. Without knowing what class you're talking about, it's hard to help you. In general: No, a set is not the same as a collection. A collection can contain the same value twice. A set cannot.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There have no documentation, then what will I do? Could you please let me know if you found any documentation about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ReadonlySet` is a type similar to `Set`, but it does not have a `add` / `delete` method, so elements can only be added during construction:

```
  const regular: Set<number> = new Set([1,2,3]);
  regular.add(4);
  
  const readonly: ReadonlySet<number> = new Set([1,2,3]);
  readonly.add(4) //fails, add not a function
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts)

Unlike the readonlySet in C#  you referenced, typescripts ReadonlySet is not actually a class/constructor. Its just a type. As typescript has duck typing, the `Set` is kind of a superclass to `ReadonlySet`, so the type can be "typecasted". This is actually only for typechecking, it has no runtime influence.At runtime, it's just a JavaScript `Set`.

Comment: Do you have any documentation about this? and provide little more explanation ?

Comment: @ramesh added a reference